# Using recursion to find derivative of a function (Three-Point Endpoint Formula)

Tags: python, recursion, derivative

I need to find the n derivative from a function using a Three-Point Endpoint formula.

[This is the general formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUpPt.png)

Can anyone help me with the code? Cause mine seems to be **really** lacking.

This is my code:

```
formula = input('Input the formula here : ')

n = input('Input the exponent here: ')

def f(x):
    return eval(formula)

fungsi = pow(formula,n)

x0 = eval(input('Input the approximation of x here : '))
h = eval(input('Input the stepsize h here : '))

def TPEP(x,h,n,formula): #Three Point End Point
    return (1/(2*h))*(-3*f(x,n-1)+4*f(x+h,n-1)-f(x+2*h,n-1))

print('Derivative of f in x0 = {0} is : '.format(x0))
print("f'({0}) = {1:.7f} (Three Point Endpoint)".format(x0,TPEP(x0,h,n,formula)))
```

I'd be really grateful if anyone could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main point is that you have to check for termination in your `TPEP`. The second thing is that you actually have to execute the recursion: you are calling `f`, not your recursive approximation of a derivative `TPEP`. With some other fixes (careful, not thoroughly tested and no error handling):

```
import math

formula = input('Input the formula here : ')
n = int(input('Input the degree of derivative here: '))

def f(formula, x):
    return eval(formula, globals(), {'x': x}) # use global and local scope

x0 = float(input('Input the approximation of x here : ')) # no error handling here - TODO
h = float(input('Input the stepsize h here : '))

def TPEP(x, h, n, formula): # Three Point End Point
    if n <= 1: # need to check for iteration stop: the grade of derivatives
        return (1/(2*h))*(-3*f(formula, x)+4*f(formula, x+h)-f(formula, x+2*h))
    return (1/(2*h))*(-3*TPEP(x,h,n-1,formula)+4*TPEP(x+h,h,n-1,formula)-TPEP(x+2*h,h,n-1,formula)) # error-term omitted

print('Derivative of f in x0 = {0} is : '.format(x0))
print("f'({0}) = {1:.7f} (Three Point Endpoint)".format(x0, TPEP(x0, h, n, formula)))
```

which produces

```
Input the formula here : x**3-3*x**2-1
Input the degree of derivative here: 2
Input the approximation of x here : 2
Input the stepsize h here : .1
Derivative of f in x0 = 2.0 is : 
f'(2.0) = 6.0000000 (Three Point Endpoint)
```

Also in your `eval` of `f`, use a variable (here local scope) to evaluate it conveniently at different `x`-values.